What's this 70's to 90's movie with a kid with healing factor
it's a color live-action american movie from either by Disney, Warner bros or 20th Century Fox (all made those kinda cool movies for kids back then). I can only vaguely remember the end. There is an underwater scene with the kid who is stuck in a car with his dog (I think). It then fades to black and we end up in a hospital where the kid is safely resting. By the way has a healing factor (like wolverine) if remember correctly.
It's likely it's a disney movie because the way I remember it I saw it on "Disney Parade" which was a french equivalent of Disneyland i believe.

Probably, you looking for "I-man".

Widowed father, his son and their dog obtain powerful healing factor.
At 1h21m Jeffrey Wilder (father) fall into the ocean, trapped inside a truck, and slowly fades to black.
It was made by Disney in 1986


sounds about right!
